# Munin won't draw iowait

Tags: munin

[Munin shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS0qC.png) high iowait (see legend), but does not reflect it on graphs.

It has default config, except the graph_height (but the problem was from beginning, before the graph_height was chnaged).

What's wrong with it? Ububtu Oneiric 32 server.

```
$munin-run cpu config | grep iowait
graph_order system user nice idle iowait irq softirq
iowait.label iowait
iowait.draw STACK
iowait.min 0
iowait.type DERIVE
iowait.info CPU time spent waiting for I/O operations to finish when there is nothing else to do.
```

Comment: What shows munin log ?? (client and server)

Comment: [PERL WARNING] Use of uninitialized value $only_fqn in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Munin/Master/GraphOld.pm line 1361

Comment: That's in munin-graph.log. And nothing specific in other logs. Upgrade to Precise didn't help either.

Comment: Hmm under some reason the sum of values is up to 1600%, while system has 8 "CPUs" so Munin tries to plot values inside 800%.